# Java - spiral move from 2-D Array inside out

Tags: java, algorithm, spiral

I am trying to realise an algorithm where I can move in an array of unknown size counterclockwise in that order:

`16 15  14  13
5   4   3   12
6   1   2   11
7   8   9   10`

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably should try on your own first instead asking for an idea. We could help if you're stuck. But asking this way doesn't show your effort.

Comment: My first solution was done with Hashmap, which was kind of an easy way to solve it. With an array, my approach was to initiate an array with n*n length. Start at the middle and use a big if/else block of currenty 10 rules. Those rules consists of checking every neighbour element if those are 0. If they arent move up/left/right/down. But it is more of a hack than a good approach I guess

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to:

1. set n to 1 and face right
2. Move n steps and turn left
3. Move n steps and turn left
4. Increase n, repeat from step 2